# Use solutions of FindRoot in subsequent calculations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I want to solve the equation $b e^a = 2$ in $b$, for values of $a$ ranging from $0$ to $10$ and each time $a$ to be increased by $0.1$. So I have:

```
FindRoot[b  E^(a ) - 2 /. a -> 0, {b, 0}]
```

Now, I can add $0.1$ to $0$, and solve it for $a = 0.1$ and so on, then I want to collect all points $(a,b)$ as a list. My first question is that: is there any faster way to do this, that is not solving and collecting points one by one.

My second question is somewhat similar to the first one: for each $(a,b)$ obtained in the above, I want to plug them in

```
p[n] := n (a) + b
```

and collect the points

```
(p[8], Sum[p[n], {n, 1, 5}])
```

again, I'm doing this one by one. I appreciate if anyone could help me to make it more easier to do.

Comment: `Solve[b*Exp[a] == 2, a, Reals]`

Comment: `pts = Cases[
   ContourPlot[Cos[a] + Cos[b] == 1/2, {a, 0, 4 Pi}, {b, 0, 4 Pi}] // 
    Normal, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];
trans[a_, b_] = {n*a + b /. n -> 8, Sum[n*a + b, {n, 1, 5}]};
newpts = Apply[trans, pts, {2}];
{Graphics[Point /@ pts], Graphics[Point /@ newpts]}`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose a way where it is obvious to see what is going on.

```
(tabab = Table[{a -> aa, First@FindRoot[b E^(aa) - 2, {b, 1}]}, {aa, 
 0, 10, 0.1}]) // TableForm

p[n_] := n (a) + b /. tabab

p[8]
```

**Edit**

```
(sum = Sum[p[n], {n, 1, 5}]) // TableForm

(tp = Transpose[{p[8], sum}]) // MatrixForm
```

Comment: @Martin  please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the roots for all the values:

```
ran = Range[0, 1, 0.1];
roots = FindRoot[b E^(a) - 2 /. a -> #, {b, 0}] & /@ ran
```

Here I've done it for the range of values in ran. Then get the list of values of the roots by:

```
b /. roots
```

or the {a,b} pairs via:

```
Thread[{ran, b /. roots}]
```

Comment: Many thanks, this reduces my labor! Could you also answer the second part, thanks!

Comment: This approach works, provided that `0` is a good initial guess for `b` for all value of `a` in the desired range.